# Postman and generated code snip for Jquery/ajax returns different data from same endpoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, postman

I developed a PHP endpoint that sends back the contents of the PHP $_POST and $_FILES global variables.  This works perfect.  The code is listed below.

```
function debug() {

    var_dump($_POST);
    var_dump($_FILES);

}
```

When I use Postman to send the "form"  form data two variables, one text, one file I get the expected format returned from the API endpoint.

```
array (size=1)  
  'subject' => string 'some subject' (length=12)  
array (size=1)  
    'uploads' =>   
     array (size=5)  
      'name' => string 'up  loadme.pdf' (length=12)  
      'type' => string '  application/pdf' (length=15)  
      'tmp_name' => string '/tmp/phpIiSqAv' (length=14)  
      'error' => int 0  
      'size' => int 12325
```

However when I press the code button I take the generated code place it in my browser I get:

```
array (size=2)
 'subject' => string 'some subject' (length=12)
 'uploads' => string '/home/ken/Documents/uploadme.pdf' (length=32)

array (size=0)
  empty
```

As can be seen the $_POST Array contains both varable and the $_FILES array is empty.

The code snip generated by postman is

```
var form = new FormData();
form.append("subject", "some subject");
form.append("uploads", "/home/ken/Documents/uploadme.pdf");

var settings = {
  "async": true,
  "crossDomain": true,
  "url": "https://localhost/mms/public/CommunicatorEmail/debug",
  "method": "POST",
  "headers": {
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "4b2b2b5b-dc9a-0e27-3a2b-cb763e816b94"
  },
  "processData": false,
  "contentType": false,
  "mimeType": "multipart/form-data",
  "data": form
}

$.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
  console.log(response);
});
```

So the question is why does the post work from postman and not from jquery/ajax generated by the code button in postman?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I spent a lot of time working with both $.ajax and the code snippet.  I stripped as much "junk" away as possible, making the simplist case and came up with

```
var fdata = new FormData();

//loop through the files in the upload input    
for (let file of $("#upload")[0].files) {        
    fdata.append("file", file);
}

//append fields from form
fdata.append("subject", "some subject");
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'public/CommunicatorEmail/debug',//the full endpoint was unnecessary in my case
    data: fdata,
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
  error: function(response){
     //do something based on the error
  }
});
```

Bottom line if you want to send file and post information to the endpoint in php and use the global variables don't use the code generated code snippet use the code I created above.

I hope this helps someone.